# SQLAlchemy - Is there a way to see what is currently in the session?

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm curious if there's a way to show what is currently in the session?

Or perhaps a way to check if the session is empty or not so that I can do something like the below.

```
if db.session:
    db.session.commit()
```

This way it will only commit if there's actually something in the session waiting to be committed.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`Session.dirty`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are following properties to check session state:

- [`Session.new`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.new) - for objects, which will be added to database.
- [`Session.dirty`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty) - for objects, which will be updated.
- [`Session.deleted`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.deleted) - for objects, which will be deleted from database.

These three properties can be used to check session state:

```
if not db.session.new and not db.session.dirty and not db.session.deleted:
    # do smth
```

However it is safe to call `session.commit()` even if there is no changes in session. If you don't do something special, you don't need to explicitly check session state before commit.

---

Also there is a private method called `Session._is_clean()`, which is used to check if there are any changes to be flushed to database. It's implemented like this:

```
def _is_clean(self):
    return not self.identity_map.check_modified() and \
        not self._deleted and \
        not self._new
```

Comment: You could use [is_modified](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.is_modified) but you're indeed better off just committing and relying on SQLAlchemy to do what's optimal. Thanks anyway for the pointers to new/dirty/deleted. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: `is_modified(obj)` is for a specific object, in this case we want to know if generally there's something pending ( in case a function makes many changes for many objects ) and then we want to decide if we want to `commit` at the end or not ..