# is sqlalchemy rollback idempodent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

So usually you have commit and rollback used as follows:

```
try:
    <use session>
    session.commit()
except:
   session.rollback()
```

Am doing something else with rollback in unittests and wondering, if you call session.rollback() and there is nothing to roll back is that okay or might it raise an error?

Was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31929035/4288043) and considering if that line:

```
if not db.session.new and not db.session.dirty and not db.session.deleted:
    # do smth
```

..needs to go before rollback if in doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.rollback):

> If no transaction is in progress, this method is a pass-through.